# How to open a pretrained PyTorch model that isn't in the Torch library?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to load some of the models from [data2vec2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/tree/0338cdc3094ca7d29ff4d36d64791f7b4e4b5e6e/examples/data2vec) so that I can execute predictions. I have, on that page, downloaded 2 models: `base_imagenet.pt` (which is one of the data2vec2 vision models) and `nlp_base.pt` (the NLP data2vec2 model).

I had hoped I could do `image_model = torch.load('/redacted-path/base_imagenet.pt')`, but this does not seem to give me a model object and [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) implies this isn't what I want - I need the model class.

I am somewhat new to PyTorch, but my impression of PyTorch is that if you want to load a model, you have two options:

First, you can define the model class yourself or import. For example, I believe the model class for data2vec2 is defined [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/blob/0338cdc3094ca7d29ff4d36d64791f7b4e4b5e6e/examples/data2vec/models/data2vec2.py#L151). However, this package doesn't have any sort of `requirements.txt` so when I try to import it that class so I can run code like:

```
import torch
from fairseq.examples.data2vec.models.data2vec2 import Data2VecMultiModel
```

I end up in this long set of `ModuleNotFound` errors because I don't have `omegaconf`, `bitarray`, `hydra-core` etc., installed. So this seems like the wrong approach, since there is no provided `requirements.txt` file that I could use to get my environment set up for this kind of approach.

The second option I've seen is to use something like `torchvision` to load a model. However, I'm unclear how to tell if the data2vec2 pretrained model is in torchvision at all. In the list of models available when I run `dir(torchvision.models)` is something called `vit_b_16`, which looks like what is in the [documentation](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/tree/0338cdc3094ca7d29ff4d36d64791f7b4e4b5e6e/examples/data2vec#vision). However, when I download the model from the data2vec2 documentation, it is called `base_imagenet.pt`, and when I run:

```
from torchvision.models import vit_b_16, ViT_B_16_Weights

image_model = vit_b_16(weights=ViT_B_16_Weights.DEFAULT)
```

It outputs:

> Downloading: "https://download.pytorch.org/models/vit_b_16-c867db91.pth" to /redacted/.cache/torch/hub/checkpoints/vit_b_16-c867db91.pth

So. What I would like to do is load a pretrained model from data2vec2 and use it to predict. I want to take an image and a set of text and use these pretrained models to create embeddings. A bit lost on how to do it.

Any advice?

Comment: I can find installation part from the GitHub page you linked (README.md), and also required packages can be found at line 180-192 of `setup.py`. After installation, 1) import the model class 2) assign it to a variable 3) load the weight

Answer (score 1):

This may not be enough to be an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment, so just putting it here until someone has a better answer...

1. This maybe too trivial, but how did you set up the environment? Did you use pip install and still get a list of ModuleNotFound errors?
2. Torchvision doesn't have the functionality of loading models & weights not inside its codebase. There is an option of using torch.hub (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/hub.html) for loading models from fairseq. However you will again face the ModuleNotFound error because it doesn't resolve dependencies for you.

So I think either way you will have to resolve the dependencies by yourself...